# cheerio js couldn't select anchor tag

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to select all download links from this HTML source:

[image: HTML source code]

This is my code:

```
export const getSingleMusic = async (url) => {
    const html = await getHtml(url)
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)

    const downloadSection =  $('#mt-modal-download .col-4')

    downloadSection.each((i, elem) => {
        console.log($(elem).find('a').html())
    })
}
```

But this is the result:

[image]

How can I select them?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery `$elem.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) returns `innerHTML`. Cheerio had `.html()` to return the `outerHTML` but as you can see from this issue [.html() returns outerHTML, while .html(html) sets innerHTML](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/16) they have changed it so `$elem.html()` now returns `innerHTML` and if we want to get the `outerHTML` then we can call `$.html($elem)`.

You have to either use `$.html()` like this:

```js
downloadSection.each((i, elem) => {
  console.log($.html($(elem).find('a')));
});
```

or just get the `$(elem).html()` directly to get the `innerHTML` which contains the anchor links:

```js
downloadSection.each((i, elem) => {
  console.log($(elem).html());
});
```

Comment: ```$.html($(elem).find('a').attr('href'))``` this doesn't work

Comment: You don't use `html()` on attributes. The attribute has a text value and you get it like this `console.log($(elem).find('a').attr('href'));`.

Comment: @ShaSha you can see it working at this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cheerio-get-links